# Deleting items in firestore based on timestamp

Tags: android, firebase, timestamp, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete items in firestore based on the documents time stamp, I'm fairly sure the code is right and I'm definitely sure the timestamps match and yet I get a null pointer

```
  java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
  'com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task 
  com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentReference.delete()' on a null object 
  reference
```

So here's what I have so far... when the activity starts I run a query and get all the message documents from firestore, I then put these into objects and display them in a recycler view with a custom adapter (basic stuff). What I'm doing now is creating a delete method, so I've created a method in my adapter that adds selected items to a list that I can get to start deleting (getSelectedItems) and I'm using the firestore query below to delete the items

```
ArrayList<UserMessage> messages = new ArrayList<>();
messages.addAll(mMessageAdapter.getSelectedItems());
final CollectionReference userRef =
            db.collection("users")
                    .document(userId)
                    .collection("contacts")
                    .document(myUser.get_id())
                    .collection("messages");
for (UserMessage message : messages) {

        System.out.println(message.getTime_stamp());
        //this prints like this- Sat Jun 02 12:20:56 GMT+01:00 2018

        Query query = userRef.whereEqualTo("time_stamp", 
        message.getTime_stamp());
        query.get().addOnCompleteListener(new 
        OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override                                                                   
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    System.out.println("found an item to delete");
                    for (DocumentSnapshot doc : task.getResult()) {
                        doc.getDocumentReference(doc.getId())
                                .delete()
                                .addOnSuccessListener(new 
                                    OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                                     System.out.println("deleted an item");
                                        messagesDeleted[0]++;
                                        prog3Message = ("Deleted " + 
                                        messagesDeleted[0] + " of " + 
                                        allMessages[0] + " messages");
                                        runOnUiThread(changeMessage);
                                    }
                                });
                    }
                    if (messagesDeleted[0] == allMessages[0]) {
                        prog3.dismiss();
                        showMenuItems = false;
                        ///selectedMessageList.clear();
                        hideShowMenu(showMenuItems);
                        mMessageAdapter.clearSelections();
                        //System.out.println("all complete ");
                    }
                } else {

                }
            }
        });
    }
```

So to start troubleshooting I added a print statement in the first query (getting all messages) for each document I print the timestamp from both the document and the object (just in case) and it prints out like this

```
I/System.out: object data Sat Jun 02 12:20:56 GMT+01:00 2018
I/System.out: document data Sat Jun 02 12:20:56 GMT+01:00 2018
I/System.out: object data Sat Jun 02 12:23:16 GMT+01:00 2018
I/System.out: document data Sat Jun 02 12:23:16 GMT+01:00 2018
```

which as you can see matches a print from the delete method above - Sat Jun 02 12:20:56 GMT+01:00 2018 - and yet i get a null pointer when running the query, one interesting fact is when you go to firestore the timestamp shows like this June 1, 2018 at 5:55:49 PM UTC+1 which is a different format and different region so i tried playing with it a little and ended up doing this (not very elegant)

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = 
new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd, yyyy HH:mm:ss aa", Locale.US);
    dateFormat.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
    String formatted = dateFormat.format(message.getTime_stamp());
        String[] parts = formatted.split(" ");
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++){
            if(i == 2){
                stringBuilder.append(parts[i] + " at ");
            }else if (i == parts.length -1){
                stringBuilder.append(parts[i].toUpperCase() + " UTC+1");
            }else{
                stringBuilder.append(parts[i] + " ");
            }
        }
        System.out.println(stringBuilder.toString());
        //June 02, 2018 at 11:20:56 AM UTC+1
```

this gives me the right pattern but the time is now an hour out can anyone tell me if I'm trying to reinvent the wheel here hopefully theres a better way

Answer (score 1):

I couldnt figure this out and decided to instead write a message to firestore and then update the item with its id so it reads collection (user) document {userId} collection (contacts) document {contactId} collection (messages) document {messageId} document values id = messageId values message = "blah blah" this way i can delete each item by its id